# Difference Between XMLReader.Create() and new XMLTextReader()

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to learn the difference between `XMLReader.Create` and `new XMLTextReader()` to read XML. Why would I choose one over the other?
Is there a performance difference?

I know XMLReader is an abstract type for XMLTextReader, at least that is what I read before, but I saw somewhere people suggested using XMLReader.Create() methods rather than new XMLReader() instance.

Thanks in advance...

Sincerely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`XmlReader.Create` allows you to specify [`XmlReaderSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx), which none of the `XmlTextReader` constructor overloads do.

Comment: That does not seem to be the only difference, I just ran into a problem where no settings could make XmlReader.Create work, but XmlTextReader works just fine:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257204/different-behaviour-between-new-xmltextreader-and-xmlreader-create

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft's answer is simply:

Although the Microsoft .NET Framework includes the XmlTextWriter class, which is an implementation of the XmlWriter class, in the 2.0 release, it is recommended that you use the Create method to create new XmlWriter objects. The Create method allows you to specify the features to support on the created XmlWriter object, and it also allows you to take full advantage of the new features introduced in the 2.0 release.

BUT that answer leaves out the most important difference:

If you call 'new XmlTextReader' it will be set in 'v1compat' mode, which will cause it to have very bad streaming behavior in certain cases, potentially leading to OutOfMemoryExceptions!  See [Why is my new XmlTextReader(stream) reading in many megabytes into memory rather than streaming properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940927/why-is-my-new-xmltextreaderstream-reading-in-many-megabytes-into-memory-rather) for more on that.

RECOMMENDATION: Unless you really need .NET 1.1 behavior, then you should NEVER call 'new XmlTextReader', instead always call 'XmlReader.Create'.

Comment: Is there a way to put XmlReader in "v1compat" mode?

Comment: Also by default XmlTextReader is vulnerable to XXE attacks, unless you explicitly set DtdProcessing=Prohibit. XmlReader has Prohibit by default. See https://www.jardinesoftware.net/2016/05/26/xxe-and-net/

Answer (score 1):

For a general answer to why this sort of code esists at all you might want to take a look at the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Using a factory method and an abstract class/interface helps you to write more general code by not tying yourself to a specific implementation.  This can help to make your code more easily able to take advantage of new features or to be used in different situations.

Comment: *sarcasm on*
Oh yes, and it makes it a realy joy to find non-trivial bugs in multiple environments.

Comment: Seriously. just a word of warning: Factory Pattern can become quickly evil and turn on their master. First, you immediately loose compile-time safety. Secondly, mainiaining consistency over many versions can become very painful. I've seen cases (some of them mine ;-) ) where the factory pattern became a necessity out of major design flaws in the system.
Don't get me wrong, all I'm saying is that in some situations they can be the best way to hide something, but in others you just want to know :-)