# Can't set settings on XmlTextReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

I need to set the MaxCharactersFromEntities on the XmlTextReader, this is my code so far :

```
xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(fileInfo.FullName);
xmlTextReader.Settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlTextReader.Settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 0;
var vr = new XmlValidatingReader(xmlTextReader);
vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
vr.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandEntities;

xmlDocument.Load(vr);
```

The Settings property is read-only so it can´t be set and its null?  How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551912/difference-between-xmlreader-create-and-new-xmltextreader/1551916#1551916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `XmlReader.Create(string, XmlReaderSettings)` instead to create your reader instance.

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the
>   System.Xml.XmlReader class instead.

The idea is to use the Create(...) factory method of the base class `XmlReader` instead of instantiating the derived class directly. Also see the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for additional info.

The rest of your code remains unaffected since `XmlValidatingReader` takes an `XmlReader` in the constructor.

So you should end up with somehting like:

```
xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 0;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileInfo.FullName, settings);

var vr = new XmlValidatingReader(reader);
vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
vr.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandEntities;

xmlDocument.Load(vr);
```

Comment: @Banshee Updated my anser to include that part, but you don't need to change anything there..

Comment: `XmlValidatingReader` is obsolete since .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to pass `XmlReaderSettings` instance upon construction of the `XmlReader` instance in the first place, rather than updating the reader's `Settings` property later -which is impossible as the property doesn't have setter- :

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

//create XmlReaderSettings first
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 80; //0 doesn't make sense here, as it's the default value

//create XmlReader later, passing the pre-defined settings
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileInfo.FullName, settings);

//the rest of the codes remain untouched
var vr = new XmlValidatingReader(xmlReader);
vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
vr.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandEntities;

xmlDocument.Load(vr);
```