# Different behaviour between "new XmlTextReader" and "XmlReader.Create"

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Given the following source code:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Schema;

 namespace TheXMLGames
 {
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings {
         Async = false,
         ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
         DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore,
         ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None,
         ValidationType = ValidationType.None,
         XmlResolver = null,
       };

       string head = File.ReadAllText("sample.xml");
       Stream stringStream = GenerateStreamFromString(head);

       // Variant 1
       //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringStream);

       // Variant 2
       //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringStream, settings);

       // Variant 3
       XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringStream);

       while (reader.Read())
         if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
           Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + ": " + reader.Value);

       // No Variant gets here without an exception,
       // but that's not the point!

       Console.ReadKey();
     }

     public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
     {
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
       writer.Write(s);
       writer.Flush();
       stream.Position = 0;
       return stream;
     }
   }
 }
```

sample.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE TestingFacility >
 <TestingFacility id="MACHINE_2015-11-11T11_11_11" version="2015-11-11">

 <Program>
   <Title>title</Title>
   <Steps>16</Steps>
 </Program>
 <Calibration>
   <Current offset="0" gain="111.11" />
   <Voltage offset="0" gain="111.11" />
 </Calibration>
 <Info type="Facilityname" value="MACHINE" />
 <Info type="Hardwareversion" value="HW11" />
 <Info type="Account" value="DJohn" />
 <Info type="Teststart" value="2015-11-11T11:11:11" />
 <Info type="Description" value="desc" />
 <Info type="Profiler" value="prof" />
 <Info type="Target" value="trgt" />
```

The behaviour is the following:

**Variant 1**
XmlReader.Create(stream)
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

**Variant 2**
XmlReader.Create(stream, settings)
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: Unexpected DTD declaration. Line 2, position 3.

**Variant 3**
new XmlTextReader(stringStream)
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: TestingFacility. Line 19, position 36.

Variant 1 and 2 throw after the first line.
Variant 3 outputs the whole file as expected and when it gets to the end, it complains (correctly!).

The software works as I obviously use Variant 3, but the (now) recommended way is to use the Factory via XmlReader.Create

If I fiddle with the settings, it starts getting even more weird.

How can I get the code up-to-date and use XmlReader.Create?

The full project can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55cC50M31_8T0lub25oS2QxQ00/view

Comment: Here's a related question (NOT a duplicate!)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551912/difference-between-xmlreader-create-and-new-xmltextreader

Comment: XmlReader Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data. XmlTextReader provides full capability.  XmlReader is newer a bugs in XmlTextReader have been fixed.

Comment: @jdweng: XmlReader is just a base class for XmlTextReader, allowing for other derived classes, e.g. to provide the same API over a DOM. It's not like one is a fixed version of the other, as you imply.

Comment: I guess the newer class is more robust than older version.  Not really a bug.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using.aspx) that contains some discussion about `XmlTextReader` vs. `XmlReader` created with the `.Create` method. For security reasons (DTD expansion DOS attack) processing DTDs is by default disabled in the `XmlReader` created with `.Create()`.

Comment: What are you doing with the `settings`?  You should pass it to the factory method - e.g. `XmlReader.Create(stringStream, settings)`.

Comment: @jdweng: Both `XmlReader` and `XmlTextReader` have existed since .NET 1.0. Which do you consider the "newer" one?

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis: Pawel's comment looks right to me. If you could provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem (complete code and complete XML) it would be easier to help you. Giving incomplete XML and only snippets of code always make it harder to help.

Comment: @JonSkeet [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) seem to imply the preferred approach is using `XmlReader.Create` in .NET 2.0 and later, unless I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: @CharlesMager: Doh! I completely agree. Massive horrible braino :) Will delete that comment and write the *correct* version instead... well spotted. Trying to do too many things at once...

Comment: @jdweng: I'll certainly agree that calling `XmlReader.Create` instead of instantiating `XmlTextReader` directly is the preferred approach, mind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally recommend using a NON XML method for parsing an XML file.  But sometimes when the XML is not valid other methods are a better choice.  Since you have a huge XML file and you are only trying to get one line of data the code below may be the best choice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                "<!DOCTYPE SomeDocTypeIdidntPutThere>\n" +
                "<TestingFacility id=\"MACHINE2_1970-01-01T11_22_33\" version=\"1970-01-01\">\n" +
                "<Program>\n" +
                  "<Title>Fancy Title</Title>\n" +
                  "<Steps>136</Steps>\n" +
                "</Program>\n" +
                "<Info type=\"Start\" value=\"2070-01-01T11:22:33\" />\n" +
                "<Info type=\"LotMoreOfThem\" value=\"42\" />\n";

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string inputLine = "";
            string timeStr = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(inputLine.StartsWith("<Info type=\"Start\""))
                {
                    string pattern = "value=\"(?'time'[^\"]+)";
                    timeStr = Regex.Match(inputLine, pattern).Groups["time"].Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            DateTime time;
            if (timeStr.Length > 0)
            {
                time = DateTime.Parse(timeStr);
            }
        }
    }
}

​
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as I mentioned before, regex is always a "solution". And the weird thing (that nobody could explain so far :-) ) is, that it works with the XmlTextReader. I understand the difficulties with incomplete XML and as I mentioned, SAX may be the better option.

I want to understand why it behaves like it does.

Comment: As i mentionded, If you use the MemoryStream approach with XmlTextReader it works fine. And i think it should also work with the correct settings for XmlReader.Create, but I can't figure them out and before I file an Issue, I just wanted to see if I forgot something crucial.

Comment: Oh, and the regex-approach is much more robust due to the unknown order of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You xml is invalid.  You are missing the closing tag and the DOCTYPE must match the root tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TestingFacility>
<TestingFacility id="MACHINE2_1970-01-01T11_22_33" version="1970-01-01">

  <Program>
    <Title>Fancy Title</Title>
    <Steps>136</Steps>
  </Program>
  <Info type="Start" value="2070-01-01T11:22:33" />
  <Info type="LotMoreOfThem" value="42" />
</TestingFacility>​
```

Comment: Please read the question (like: to the end)
But thanks anyway, I will make the DTD match the closing tag, altough, that should be ignored completely by the given settings. Also: The exception is not about the incorrect naming!